# Overriding the connect call using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, network-programming, overriding

I connect to the remote host using the following `connect()` call:

```
result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);
```

where the address represents the `sockaddr_in` structure, casted to `sockaddr *` for purpose of the `connect()` execution. However, using library injection I am able to override the connect call by defining my own connect function:

```
int connect (int fd, __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG addr, socklen_t len)
{
   // My code in between
}
```

I am however unable to cast the second argument (the `__CONST_SOCAKADDR_ARG`) to the `sockaddr_in` pointer or `sockaddr` for that matter. `__CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG` macro expands to `const struct sockaddr *`. The following line:

```
struct sockaddr_in* providedIPv4AddressStructure = (struct sockaddr_in*) addr;
```

gets me to the following error indications:

```
error: cannot convert to a pointer type
```

and of course:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Anyone has any hints on how to properly cast the `__CONST_SOCAKADDR_ARG` to `sockaddr_in *`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you changing the second arg to `const?`

Comment: I am actually trying to override the:
`int connect(int socket, const struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len);`
defined as such in `<sys/socket.h>`. So my question is really: "How to properly cast a const pointer to a non-const pointer (e.g. in my case `const sockaddr *` to `sockaddr *`)?

Comment: Yes, this is taken from `socket.h`:
 `# define __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG const struct sockaddr *`

Comment: So why do you need to cast it to a non-const?

Comment: To be able to express it as a `sockaddr_in` structure and make use of its members (in a read-only fashion).

Comment: If you're using it read-only why cast away 'const'?

Comment: I was getting the error also by just casting to any other datatype (`const sockaddr *` needs to be casted to `const sockaddr_in *` in order to access its IPv4 members). Check my comment on the answer below for how I got it working. Not sure how macro expansion can affect the casting of constant function arguments to another data types, but it does?!

Answer (score 1):

Unable to reproduce:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main() {
    __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG p;
    struct sockaddr_in *q;

    q = (struct sockaddr_in *) p;
}
```

No errors, only warnings from the unused variables:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:25: warning: variable ‘q’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
test.c:9:7: warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Comment: I tried overriding the connect() call without hoping for macro expansion:

`int connect (int fd, const struct sockaddr * addr, socklen_t len)
{
//my code here
}`

instead of using the `__CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG` and funnily enough, it worked, no compiler warnings, nothing. The code compiled seamlessly.